# How to solve "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget." in main.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have main.dart as below:

```
//main.dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'src/loginPage.dart';
import 'src/tabsPage.dart';

void main() async {
  Widget _defaultPage = new LoginPage();
  runApp(MyApp(defaultPage: _defaultPage));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget defaultPage;

  const MyApp({Key key, @required this.defaultPage}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Gaia',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: defaultPage,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/tabs': (BuildContext context) => new TabsPage(),
        '/login': (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

//LoginPage.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../main.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _State();
}

class _State extends State<LoginPage> {
  TextEditingController userIdController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void login() async {
     Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/tabs');
  }

  void forgotPassword() {
    print("Forgot password!");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
                    child: Text(
                      'Gaia',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 30),
                    )),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    maxLength: 6,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    controller: userIdController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'User Id',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                      counter: Spacer(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                  child: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    obscureText: true,
                    controller: passwordController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'password',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50),
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 30, 100, 0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'ログイン',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          login();
                        })),
                SizedBox(height: 120),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Forgot password'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    forgotPassword();
                  },
                  textColor: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('Information'),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('Here'),
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

when I run it that show me warning message, what can I solve it?

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a _Decorator widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  SizedBox.shrink ← Expanded ← Spacer ← _Decorator ← InputDecorator ← AnimatedBuilder ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← RawGestureDetector ← TextSelectionGestureDetector ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5770
#1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5786
#2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5808
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5501
#4      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6117
...
```

Comment: can you please share the code of LoginPage()

Comment: Updated my code.

Comment: the error was because of expanded widget but login page doesn't contain  any Expanded, have you use this widget in TabsPage()? try to wrap Expanded with column or Container and give any specific height.

Comment: There is no Widget `Expanded` in TabsPage, what can I do?

Comment: try to replace ListView with Column maybe this error was because of ListView

Comment: Column has same error.

Comment: Remove the SizeBox and run the project

Comment: No `SizeBox` is used:(

Comment: There are multiple SizeBox in login page

Comment: You mean `SizedBox`?

Comment: Even removed two SizedBox, same result.

Comment: Try to remove different widget. until you find the widget that causing you the error :)  and pls don't forget to tell us, what work for you.

Comment: Try removing the `Spacer` widgets that you used in your text fields.

Comment: Great! The warning is gone, but how can I hide count for TextField?